# Mapping multiple objects in dapper using Split-on and Query Multiple together

Tags: dapper

Consider **Role-Employee-Address**

An employee can have only one role but can have many addresses. So using split on is not efficient as we may get the duplicates of roles and employee. We can use query multiple, but i feel if there is a way we can capture the role and employee together in one result and address in another, then that would be better.

In that case, instead of returning role and employee separately, we can directly join both in a single query and split on some column while mapping.

I'm expecting something like this

```
string query = "StoredProcedure";

using (var multi = connection.QueryMultiple(query, null))
{
    empRole = multi.Read<Employee,Role>().Single().SplitOn("Id");
    add = multi.Read<Address>().ToList();
}
```

Is there any way we could do like this using both the techniques together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, you need a One-To-Many mapping which is not natively supported by Dapper, but can be easily implemented if the database you're using supports JSON. Here's an article I wrote (along with working samples) that shows how you can do it using SQL Server / Azure SQL:

https://medium.com/dapper-net/one-to-many-mapping-with-dapper-55ae6a65cfd4

Comment: That is cool! But how does it compare to QueryMultiple in performance for a complex object?

Comment: QueryMultiple cannot help if you have some nested relationships. If you have complex object to be returned, you will have better performance using the JSON technique.
https://medium.com/dapper-net/handling-multiple-resultsets-4b108a8c5172

Comment: Hey, im trying to map the resultant JSON to string so that i can deserialize it to a object. But the result is being mapped to more than one string. Like, we generally map it to a IEnumerable<T> and as the query is returning only one row, im expecting it to fill only the 1st object in the list. But that is not the case. Im having to append all the strings in the list to deserialize the object. Can you help me with this?

Comment: I would recommend to create a specific question for this also with a code sample, as I'm not sure I got the problem...

Comment: I have posted a question about this here =>
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53846502/mapping-json-response-from-sql-server-to-a-single-string