# Dapper multipmap

Tags: c#, dapper

I have the following in my db with a junction/xref table
[image]

I would like to map it to the following object

```
 public class Coin : CoinBase
{


    public IEnumerable<CoinAnnouncement> Announcements { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<CoinCategory> Categories { get; set; }


}
```

I would like to include annoucements in one go as well if possible (not showing in the db image)

Here is my dapper call

```
 using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            return await conn.QueryAsync<Coin, CoinCategory, Coin>(
                @"SELECT c.CoinId, c.Userid, c.IconPath, c.LastPriceBtc, c.LastUpdatedUtc, c.Name, c.Rank,
                         c.Symbol, c.LogoPath, c.Description, c.SubReddit, c.TwitterScreenName, c.Website, c.Discord,
                         c.FacebookPage, c.Telegram
                FROM Coins c
                INNER JOIN CoinCategoriesCategories coinCat ON coinCat.CoinId = c.CoinId
                INNER JOIN CoinCategories cat ON cat.CategoryId = coinCat.CategoryID", 
                (coin, coinCat) => {

                    coin.Categories = coinCat; //problem figuring out what this line would look like
                    return coin;
                });
        }
```

I essentially want to just ignore the xref/junction table and directly map the categories to the coin object

Comment: The answer to your question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53757053/mapping-multiple-objects-in-dapper-using-split-on-and-query-multiple-together

Answer (score 0):

Solved it based on https://www.tritac.com/blog/dappernet-by-example

```
      var lookup = new Dictionary<int, Coin>();

        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            var result = await conn.QueryAsync<Coin, CoinCategoryCategory, CoinCategory, Coin>(
                @"SELECT c.*, coinCat.*, cat.*
                    FROM Coins c
                    INNER JOIN CoinCategoriesCategories coinCat ON coinCat.CoinId = c.CoinId
                    INNER JOIN CoinCategories cat ON cat.CategoryId = coinCat.CategoryID", 
                (c, cat, coinCat) =>
                {

                    Coin coin;
                    if (!lookup.TryGetValue(c.CoinId, out coin))
                    {
                        lookup.Add(c.CoinId, coin = c);
                    }
                    if (coin.Categories == null)
                        coin.Categories = new List<CoinCategory>();
                    coin.Categories.Add(new CoinCategory { CategoryId = coinCat.CategoryId, Description = coinCat.Description });
                    return coin;
                }, splitOn: "CategoryId, CoinId");

            return lookup.Values;
        }
```